# opta planner course curriculum assign Particular Room to a Course

Tags: optaplanner

I have a scenario that Course should assigned to a particular rooms.

Example,

Course is Java programming, Teacher Name : James, Room: ROOM1,LAB1,ROOM2.

I want to assign this course to a Lab since the course is a Programming. I can provide Lab as a class room. How to restrict that, this course should go into a particular Room (Lab)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: add a type field to the Room (or a list of types) and create a score constraint to penalize every course which requires a lab and doesn't get assigned to one. Of course, add a required type of room field to the Course.

Comment: Hello Sir,I am very new to OptaPlanner. could you please elaborate more or possible to write piece of code, which will help me a lot.

Comment: The docs might help you out (http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html), specifically for score calculation: http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#cloudBalancingScoreConfiguration

Comment: I have added a ctype instance variable in Course Class with Setter and getter methods 
and rtype in Room Class.
The following rule has been added,  but still unable to restrict

example input:

COURSES:
math t1 2 1 100 C
science t1 1 1 80 L
french t2 1 1 20 C
cpro t2 5 10 20 L

ROOMS:
Lab 90 L
Class 110 C


rule "labAssigntoItCourse"
    when
         $course : Course($ctype : ctype)
         $room : Room($rtype : rtype)
         $result:Course($room.getRtype()==$course.getCtype())
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, 100);
end

Comment: any suggestion on the above rule?, especially this line scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, 100);

Comment: Please, read the docs. Rules should generally not give bonuses, but rather penalize: I'd change the rule to check for `Rtype != Ctype`, and then `addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1)`

Answer (score 0):

I did that and it worked fine.

```
rule "..."
    when
         $room : Room($roomType : getRoomType())
         $course : Course($courseType : getCourseType())
         Lecture(room==$room ,course==$course , $roomType!=$courseType )
    then scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -10);
end
```